# Move text selection backwards with "shortcut"

Tags: shortcuts

Is it possible to to move the "back" of the selection, like we can use "shift-arrow" to move the "front" of the selection when selecting text.

An example:
"some-string-word"

Where we double click to select "string", but wanna expand the selection to contain "some-string".

Comment: Afaik, you can't do this easily with the keyboard. But, you you can Shift+Double Click on the word "some".

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left arrow</kbd>, at least in some text editors like Gedit.

In other context, instead of selecting the word, place yourself to the end of the word and apply the same shortcut.

[image]

Comment: That only selects "some-" and de-selects "string". Now, if you were to select "some" first, then you could do <CTRL><SHIFT><RIGHT ARROW> to select "some-string", but I think that is not what is being asked for.

Comment: @PJSingh I tested this in gedit and works... but you are right, it's not a standard behaviour.